# Refactoring old products table with many differents

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to refactor an old mysql database of products, which is divided into tables that store characteristics of different types of products.

That is to say, not all products have the same number of characteristics, and some of them influence the price of the product while others do not. So I don't see clearly if  need a pivot table to manage relations between products and its features.

I can represent this as a hardware store where there are everything from screws to tools, going through some materials such as iron and wood.

For example, if we consider screws, under the name screw we have different sizes and types (for wood, for metal, millimeter thread or self-drilling), each size and type combination will determine a price, but maybe the color of the screws don't affect prices

So I was thinking of the following table structure:

products:
id | name_id | feature_id | price

product_names:
id | name

product_features:
id | name | description

But it is not clear to me how to deal with the situation that a product may have more than one feature and not all are relevant for it's price.

Thank you for any suggestion.

---

Based on the exchange of opinions, I arrived at this concept of a diagram. I would like to know if you see it as appropriate.

[image: Diagram]

Comment: I’m not sure why you’ve created a product_names table? Can a feature relate to only one product or to many products? If it’s to only one product then you need a product_id in the feature table (the reverse of the relationship you have). If it’s a m:m relationship then you need an intersection table

Comment: If 1 product can have multiple features than you have "one to many" relationship. But, different products can have same features than it is not "one to many" but "many to many". You need join table. Since you have a business logic around feature and price I would add a flag "affects_price" inside join table. btw: "product_feature" should be join table, and just a "feature" should be feature table.

Comment: @NickW As the product name may be repeated, as there may be 1" Wood Screw, 1.5" Wood Screw, etc. I thought it was convenient to have that layout, but I'm quite open to rethinking these tables because none of them are quite suitable for me.

Comment: @salerokada Your suggestion about adding a flag sound interesting to me, because it should solve the point that some features affects price an others not. I think that features should be a many to many relationship with products because some features, like colors are not "exclusives".  The name product_features is due to the existence of other feature table, but I got your point so I will think on renaming that.

Comment: 1”, 1.5” etc is a feature/attribute (the length) of the single product “wood screw”

Comment: @NickWI think you hit the mark! Ok, size it's a feature which affect price and the name of the product is just Wood Screw, so feature table should have a price column?

Comment: The feature table should have a column for feature type and a column for feature value. Don’t hard code each feature type as its own column as that design as no flexibility

Comment: @NickW, I've edited my question to add a diagram based in my interpretation from your suggestions.